# How to remove the legend from a plot in R?

Tags: r, openair

I'd appreciate help on how to remove a legend from a plot. Say we have this:

[image]

I want to remove the "PM2.5" and the corresponding red line at the bottom of the plot. I wish it to be blank, the reason for this is because I'm using the `print` and `split` functions to create a custom plot showing 3 different monitoring sites for air pollution analysis like this:

[image]

I do not wish to have 3 legends, just one at the bottom.

Comment: hi, please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see how you got your plots

Comment: Hi, thing is that I don't know how to do that, but I can tell you how:

These plots were produced using the "openair" package. More specifically:

timePlot(subset(data, site=="Monitoring site #XX), pollutant="pm2.5", avg.time="day", type="site")

Comment: if the first link didn't help you, maybe check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Use three backticks ( ` x3) to delimit the text you want to put as code. If you don't know how to make your code reproducible, use some datasets included in R (```iris``` or ```mtcars``` for example), or use ```dput``` on a subset of your data to generate the code necessary to reproduce your data. All of these steps are described in the two links I provided you

Answer (score -1):

To turn off the legend of openair's timePlot, set "key" to FALSE.